# Making a family card game playable online

Tags: online, playing-cards

My family has a version of "Muggins" that has been handed down from generation to generation (at least 3 generations, maybe more).   The rules that we play by are different than other versions that I've been able to find online or in rule books.

I'd really like to be able to make this game playable online so that our family can log in and play it together over the internet.  What is the best way to define the rules of a card game into a multi-player internet website?

Comment: What site are you talking about?

Answer (score 9):

[VASSAL](http://www.vassalengine.org/) was made for precisely this: it's a game engine/website where you can build games, and then play the games you built online. There are a wide variety of existing games already built for VASSAL, but Muggins is not one of them.

This will not be simple: you're going to need to learn how to program the game using VASSAL's editor. It'll take time and effort, but you *will* be able to re-create your family game of Muggins, house rules and all. Once you've built the game (the site calls it a "module"), VASSAL will host the game, so your family can join; you don't need to worry about the details of building a website yourself. VASSAL is free, though the site appreciates donations to keep it running.

Answer (score 5):

You should definitely keep track of [CardForest](http://www.cardforest.com).

It is designed specifically for card games and it will let your create your version of 'Muggins' by simply specifying the rules in an online code editor.

(Disclaimer: I'm the founder)
(working hard to launch by June, 2014)

Comment: You're a few months behind! Any updates?

Comment: @Jefromi Yep, sorry, the project has been de-prioritized and it's now being developed as a side-project over the weekends. It will possibly be released as open-source eventually (some parts are already released at https://github.com/amitport?tab=repositories and https://github.com/CardForest). I'll notify of any real progress.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a very old question, but if the goal is just to play the game with your family (who already know the rules) then the *easy* way to make it happen is to just get a copy of Tabletop Simulator (or comparable software), which is just a virtual physics environment built for board/card game playing.

You can just load a deck of cards into it and drag them around, and handle the rules yourselves. Just a few dollars of investment, and no need to learn programming.